# Detecting Tap & Hold in UITableView cells

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, gesture

How do we detect a tap & hold on a `UITableViewCell`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In iOS 3.2 or later you can use [`UILongPressGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 6):

Here's the code lifted straight from my app. You should add these methods (and a boolean _cancelTouches member) to a class you derive from UITableViewCell.

```
-(void) tapNHoldFired {
    self->_cancelTouches = YES;
   // DO WHATEVER YOU LIKE HERE!!!
}
-(void) cancelTapNHold {
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(tapNHoldFired) object:nil];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    self->_cancelTouches = NO;
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    [self performSelector:@selector(tapNHoldFired) withObject:nil afterDelay:.7];
}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self cancelTapNHold];
    if (self->_cancelTouches)
        return;
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self cancelTapNHold];
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self cancelTapNHold];
    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: You should never use code like this

    self->_cancelTouches = YES;

Instead of just use

    self.cancelTouches = YES;

and declare property private

Comment: What is this syntax "->_" ? never seen it before :)

Answer (score 6):

```
//Add  gesture to a method where the view is being created. In this example long tap is added to tile (a subclass of UIView):

    // Add long tap for the main tiles
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longTap:)];
    [tile addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
    [longPressGesture release];

-(void) longTap:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    NSLog(@"gestureRecognizer= %@",gestureRecognizer);
    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        NSLog(@"longTap began");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably handle the *UIControlTouchDown* event and depending on what you mean by "hold", fire a NSTimer that will count an interval since you initiated the touch and invalidate upon firing or releasing the touch (*UIControlTouchUpInside* and *UIControlTouchUpOutside* events). When the timer fires, you have your "tap & hold" detected.

Comment: I'm can of not enough expert to come from this answer to actual code... But I mean by Hold the same behaviour in Mobile Safari when tapping and holding an URL to have an action sheet pop up to show options regarding this URL